# Detect if Solaris has chown restricted

Tags: solaris, chown

I am trying to chown a file, and I am getting a `Not owner`message

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS host001 5.10 Generic_138888-03 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
bash-3.00$ id
uid=60010(user1) gid=910(web)
bash-3.00$ ls -l file.ext
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user1  web        17449 Feb 14 10:53 file.ext
bash-3.00$ chown user2 file.ext
chown: file.ext: Not owner
```

How could I detect if this machine has restricted chown usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getconf _POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED /` checks the setting on the `/` directory, POSIX allows different paths to have different values, such as local filesystems vs. NFS, hence the requirement to include a path to the directory or file you want to know about.

Answer (score 1):

As root:

```
echo "rstchown/D" | adb -k /dev/ksyms
```

If this returns "rstchown: 1", then you cannot chown unless root.  You can add:

```
set rstchown = 0
```

to `/etc/system` to change this behavior.

Comment: Isn't there any way to check without root permission?

Comment: It's probably set to 1 because that is the default and you can't seem to chown files as a regular user.

Comment: Note that the above is for Solaris 10 and earlier. Solaris 11 replaced the /etc/system global option with a `rstchown` mount option for each mount point.